# Dropdown menu cut off, right side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu on the right side of the screen for my users. But it keeps getting cut off and is hiding my text.

[image: Before]

When I hover over my dropdown, it gets completely cut off and hides my welcome text on the screen.

[image: After]

My HTML Markup:

```
<header>
        <div>

             <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
                        require './includes/dbh.inc.php';
                        /*$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT fnidUser, lnidUsers FROM users"); */
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT fnidUser FROM users");

                        echo "

                    <div class='dropdown' style='float:right;'>
                        <li class='login current2'><a href='#'>Welcome</a>
                            <div class='dropdown-content'>
                                <ul>
                                    <li style='font-size:25px;'><a href='#'>My Account</a></la>
                                    <li style='font-size:25px;'><a href='#'>My Orders</a></la>
                                    <li style='font-size:25px;'><a href='#'>My Wishlist</a></la>
                                    <li style='font-size:25px;'><a href='#'>My Cart</a></la>
                                    <li style='font-size:25px;'><a href='#'>Log out</a></la>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </div>

                        ";
                }
                    else{
                        echo "<li class='login current2'><a href='login.php'>Login / Sign up</a></li>";
                    }
            ?>

        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="branding">
                <h1><a href="index.php" title="Home"><img src="./Header Image/header.png"></a></h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="apple.php">Apple</a></li>
                    <li><a href="samsung.php">Samsung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gadgets.php">Gadgets</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

My CSS Style for this page(side note, I attempted to make the text size smaller and for some reason it doesn't seem to work):

```
/* Global */
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button_1 {
    height: 49px;
    width: 144px;
    background: #FF3B3F;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button_1:hover{
    background-color: #752021;
    color: #CCCCCC;
}

.button_1, .roundbutton:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

img{
    user-drag: none; 
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

body{
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.footerc{
    float: left;
}

.footerb{
    float: right;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


/* Login Page Stuff */
#login_page{
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#login_page h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FF3B3F;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 12px #000000;
}

/* Header */
header{
    background: #35424A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #FF3B3F 5px solid;
}

header ul a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}

header li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

header #branding{
    float: left;
}

header #branding h1{
    margin: 0;
}

header nav{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a{
    color: #FF3B3F;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header .current2 a{
    color: #FF3B3F;
}

header a:hover{
    color: #CCCCCC;
}

.login a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}

.login {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Login Form Style */

section #login_page td .form{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}



/*Showcase*/
#showcase{
    min-height: 500px;
    background:url('../img/iphone_showcase.png') no-repeat -50px -50px;
    border-bottom: #FF3B3F 5px solid;
    /*Scroll Parallax*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#showcase h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FF3B3F;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 12px #000000;
}


/* Boxes */
#boxes{
    margin-top: 65px;
}

#boxes .box{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 25px;
}

#boxes .button_1{
    align-content: center;
}

#boxes .box2{
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    min-height: 100px;
}


/* Footer */
footer{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    border-top: #FF3B3F 5px solid;
    background-color: #35424A;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

footer .fpara, footer .logo{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

footer nav{
    float: right;
}

footer li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.fbhover{
    background: url('../footer image/facebook_hover_no.png') no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-top: 42px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fbhover:hover{
    background: url('../footer image/facebook_hover_yes.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.instahover{
    background: url('../footer image/insta_hover_no.png') no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-top: 42px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.instahover:hover{
    background: url('../footer image/insta_hover_yes.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.trhover{
    background: url('../footer image/twitter_hover_no.png') no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-top: 42px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.trhover:hover{
    background: url('../footer image/twitter_hover_yes.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.sphover{
    background: url('../footer image/support_hover_no.png') no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-top: 42px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.sphover:hover{
    background: url('../footer image/support_hover_yes.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}


/* Apple Store */
section #applestore{
    margin-top: 65px;
}




.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}






/* Store Sections */
#main {
    padding:20px 0;
}
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content #left, #content #right {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 63%;
}
#content #right {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
#content h3 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #F6F6F6); /* FF 3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #F6F6F6); /* IE10 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #F6F6F6)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #F6F6F6); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #F6F6F6); /* Opera 11.10 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#F6F6F6'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#F6F6F6')"; /* IE8+ */
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #F6F6F6); /* the standard */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    color: #3C3C3C;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 11px 0 12px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#content ul {
    list-style:none outside none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#content #left ul li {
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    width: 33%;
}
#content #left ul li:hover {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
#content #right ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content #right ul li:hover {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
#content #right ul li:first-child {
    border-width: none;
}
#content #left ul li .img {
    text-align: center;
}
#content #right ul li .img {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 94px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 113px;
}
#content #left ul li .img img {
    height:128px;
    width:128px;
}
#content #right ul li .img img {
    height:70px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    width:70px;
}
#content #left ul li .info {
    padding: 17px 20px 0 19px;
}
#content #right ul li .info {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 17px 0 0 21px;
    width: 164px;
}
#content ul li .info .title {
    color: #4B4B4B;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 150px;
}
#content ul li .info .title:hover {
    color: #049733;
}
#content #left ul li .info p {
    color: #7F7F7F;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
#content #left ul li .info .price {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
    color: #383838;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 17px 0 10px;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 8px;
}
#content #right ul li .info .price {
    color: #383838;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
#content #left ul li .info .price .st {
    color: #7F7F7F;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#content #right ul li .info .price .usual, #content #right ul li .info .price .special {
    color: #7F7F7F;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
#content #right ul li .info .price .special {
    color: #FD7A01;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content #left ul li .info .actions {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content #left ul li .info .actions a {
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    color: #fd7a01;
    display: block;
    float:right;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content #left ul li .info .actions a:first-child {
    color: #009832;
    float:left;
}
```

If you can provide me a solution it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @CoreyRinda, it would help a lot having a complete markup to check this out. _**Help us to help you**_. Thanks.

Comment: with position:absolute of drop-content, give right: 40px, adjust based on your requirement

Comment: .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 40px;
}

Comment: Okay, @ChrisTapay I added it for you.

Comment: @NagaSaiA i put that into my class dropdown-content and I do not get a different outcome.

Comment: @CoreyRinda, try for class- dropdown

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the position attributes for your `position: absolute`.
By adding:

```
right: 0;
top: 10px;
```

solves the issue (of course, you can custom that for your needs)

**Working example**: https://codepen.io/cdtapay/pen/OdRowv